# How to convert pixels stored in a list into an image with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, list, image-processing

```
pix = [
    [[90, 94, 6], [126, 108, 24], [180, 116, 42], [166, 116, 46], [72, 94, 31]],
    [[101, 96, 14], [190, 165, 84], [202, 134, 63], [170, 115, 50], [40, 50, 0]],
    [[145, 125, 53], [150, 112, 40], [148, 73, 6], [156, 90, 31], [25, 11, 1]],
    [[133, 124, 57], [165, 142, 75], [195, 142, 77], [169, 120, 62], [82, 74, 28]],
    [[73, 105, 40], [56, 77, 10], [138, 135, 67], [97, 95, 34], [45, 69, 21]],
]
```

I have a bunch of pixels stored in the list and now I want to convert it to an image. How can I turn that list into an image? Thank you

Comment: with numpy you can `numpy.array(pix)` and with cv2 you can `cv2.imwrite` your array as an image

Answer (score 4):

Using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html), you can create an image using an array:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.fromarray(np.array(pix).astype(np.uint8))
```

Now, you may look at the image:

```
img.show()
```

[image]

Good thing is, from now on, you can benefit from all of PIL's toolcase for image processing (resize, thumbnail, filters, ...).

Comment: This is not the image you will get from the OP's data! It should be orange-coloured where you have blue. PIL uses RGB ordering and you have re-ordered the OP's data into BGR ordering!

Comment: Well seen. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: How to change it into RGB ordering? @MarkSetchell

Comment: @GedePawitradi It depends on what you are planning to do next, and your question is very vague. I don't even know what ordering your original data was in... nor if you plan to process it using PIL or OpenCV/Numpy. Please click `edit` under your question and improve it so I (and others) can assist you better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/). By default, OpenCV uses Numpy arrays to display images so you can simply convert the list into a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Result:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pix = [
    [[90, 94, 6], [126, 108, 24], [180, 116, 42], [166, 116, 46], [72, 94, 31]],
    [[101, 96, 14], [190, 165, 84], [202, 134, 63], [170, 115, 50], [40, 50, 0]],
    [[145, 125, 53], [150, 112, 40], [148, 73, 6], [156, 90, 31], [25, 11, 1]],
    [[133, 124, 57], [165, 142, 75], [195, 142, 77], [169, 120, 62], [82, 74, 28]],
    [[73, 105, 40], [56, 77, 10], [138, 135, 67], [97, 95, 34], [45, 69, 21]],
]

# Convert to ndarray
img = np.array(pix).astype(np.uint8)

# Save image
cv2.imwrite('img.png', img)

# Display image
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above transforms your list into a `PIL Image`. If you just want to *see* the image, you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(pix)
```